# Azure Logic Apps Workflow() function - Missing Parameter Information

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We currently have a few logic apps that are triggering from the Finance & Operations trigger connection. We are using the function, workflow() to pull out the relevant logic app information to add back into Salesforce to help with troubleshooting etc.

Our typical workflow() output has been the same across all of the logic apps except for a handful where it is missing the subscription information where we are parsing out the Resource Group (used for something else) and causes the entire LA to fail.  However, when we rerun the job the provides the expected workflow() output.

---

Example of what we typically get (and what we get on a rerun)

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/**SUBSCRIPTION**/resourceGroups/FC-CUS-UAT-INT-RG/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/fc-cus-uat-int-ala-p2p-fno-address-update-asb",
  "name": "fc-cus-uat-int-ala-p2p-fno-address-update-asb",
  "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
  "location": "centralus",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "LogicApp"
  },
  "run": {
    "id": "/subscriptions/**SUBSCRIPTION**/resourceGroups/FC-CUS-UAT-INT-RG/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/fc-cus-uat-int-ala-p2p-fno-address-update-asb/runs/08585180469624071707983501726CU26",
    "name": "08585180469624071707983501726CU26",
    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs"
  }
```

**What we get when the Logic app is triggered by the platform event**

```
{
  "id": "/workflows/80908dab5a174cb995bec973da7114f7",   <--- We aren't getting the subscription info
  "name": "fc-cus-uat-int-ala-p2p-fno-address-update-asb",
  "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
  "location": "centralus",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "LogicApp"
  },
  "run": {
    "id": "/workflows/80908dab5a174cb995bec973da7114f7/runs/08585180469978755690410386818CU00",
    "name": "08585180469978755690410386818CU00",
    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs"
  }
}
```

- We looked at how the other Logic apps were setup and everything is on Consumption and this isn't impacting any other of the Logic apps.
- We tried to remove the trigger and re-add and got the same results
- We reverted to the legacy connector for CDS (what we are using for Finance and Operations) and same issue

Any help or insight will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you everyone :D